# alternative to update_option() in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I know this is a fairly recent feature in WordPress version is 2.8.6 ( at the time of writing).

There are some functions that allow you to easily create **panels** in the `wp-admin`. You're supposed to be able to just define a function and a form, and WordPress will handle the `update_option()` calls.

I haven't had much success in hunting it down though. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally tracked it down:

http://digwp.com/2009/09/global-custom-fields-take-two/